# How to create anaconda python environment in pycharm with all the packages?

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda

How to create anaconda python environment in pycharm with all the packages from anaconda?

[image]

when I try import numpy, it says numpy is not recognised but I already have numpy installed with anaconda?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install `numpy` in your new environment. In your command prompt type `conda activate condaProject_1` and then `pip install numpy`

This is useful because you can have different `numpy` versions in each environment. They are completely independent and don't share installed packages.

Comment: Ivan so pycharm doesn't inherit the packages that came with anaconda?

Comment: You are using the `python` from your `condaProject_1 `environment in pycharm. When you create this environment you **only** have the python version you chose, Nothing else (no package).  As you are using this `python` in pycharm, you don't get anything else and you have to reinstall what you need.

Comment: Right, then what is the point of having anaconda plugins in pycharm?

Comment: Well, in this case anaconda helps you having different environments with different python installations. I don't know what else